# Error while executing data provider - Pimcore DynamicSearch

Tags: lucene, pimcore

I have migrated to Pimcore X incl. DynamicSearch, DS Lucene and Trinity (~2.0.0) bundles. If we run the command "bin/console dynamic-search:run -v" which should trigger indexing the documents, we get the following result/error message:

```
[2022-02-01T16:29:53.554316+01:00] [workflow] [websitedocs] ERROR: Error while executing data provider. Error was: Error while executing processing index document (index) via provider. Error was: "DynamicSearchBundle\Exception\ProviderException::__construct(): Argument #3 ($previousException) must be of type ?Exception, Error given, called in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/vendor/dachcom-digital/dynamic-search-index-provider-lucene/src/DsLuceneBundle/Provider/LuceneIndexProvider.php on line 114". [Line: 201, File /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/vendor/dachcom-digital/dynamic-search/src/DynamicSearchBundle/Processor/ResourceModificationProcessor.php]. FailOver has been initiated
[2022-02-01T16:29:53.554440+01:00] [trinity_data] [websitedocs] DEBUG: executing provider emergency shutdown
[2022-02-01T16:29:53.554549+01:00] [lucene] [websitedocs] DEBUG: executing provider emergency shutdown
```

Our database_name in the config (index_provider) is "websitedocs".

```
dynamic_search:
    enable_pimcore_element_listener: true
    context:
        websitedocs:
            index_provider:
                service: 'lucene'
                options:
                    database_name: 'websitedocs'
                    analyzer:
                        # forced_locale: de
                        filter:
                          stemming:
                              on_index_time: true
                              on_query_time: true
                              locale_aware: false
                              class: '\DsLuceneBundle\Lucene\Filter\Stemming\SnowBallStemmingFilter'
                          stop_words:
                              on_index_time: true
                              on_query_time: true
                              libraries:
                                  -   locale: de
                                      file: '%%dsl_stop_words_lib_path%%/de'
                                  -   locale: en
                                      file: '%%dsl_stop_words_lib_path%%/en'
            data_provider:
                service: 'trinity_data'
                normalizer:
                    service: 'trinity_localized_resource_normalizer'
                    options:
                        locales: ['de']
                options:
                    always:
                        index_object: false
                        index_document: true
                        index_asset: false
            output_channels:
                autocomplete:
                    service: 'lucene_autocomplete'
                suggestions:
                    service: 'lucene_suggestions'
                    normalizer:
                        service: 'lucene_document_key_value_normalizer'
                    options:
                        phrased_search: true
                        fuzzy_search: true
                        wildcard_search: true
                search:
                    service: 'lucene_search'
                    use_frontend_controller: true
                    normalizer:
                        service: 'lucene_document_key_value_normalizer'
                    options:
                        phrased_search: true
                        fuzzy_search: true
                        wildcard_search: true
                    paginator:
                        enabled: true
                        max_per_page: 50
```

With Pimcore 6.9 and DS (0.7) the search did work. Does anyone know what is causing this error or what we could do to solve the problem? Thanks for any help.

**Upate (Configuration adjusted):**

```
dynamic_search:
    enable_pimcore_element_listener: true
    context:
        websitedocs:
            index_provider:
                service: 'lucene'
                options:
                    database_name: 'websitedocs'
                    # analyzer:
                    #     # forced_locale: de
                    #     filter:
                    #       stemming:
                    #           on_index_time: true
                    #           on_query_time: true
                    #           locale_aware: false
                    #           class: '\DsLuceneBundle\Lucene\Filter\Stemming\SnowBallStemmingFilter'
                    #       stop_words:
                    #           on_index_time: true
                    #           on_query_time: true
                    #           libraries:
                    #               -   locale: de
                    #                   file: '%%dsl_stop_words_lib_path%%/de'
                    #               -   locale: en
                    #                   file: '%%dsl_stop_words_lib_path%%/en'
            data_provider:
                service: 'trinity_data'
                normalizer:
                    service: 'trinity_localized_resource_normalizer'
                    # options:
                    #     locales: ['de']
                options:
                    always:
                        index_object: false
                        index_document: true
                        index_asset: false
            output_channels:
                autocomplete:
                    service: 'lucene_autocomplete'
                suggestions:
                    service: 'lucene_suggestions'
                    normalizer:
                        service: 'lucene_document_key_value_normalizer'
                    options:
                        phrased_search: true
                        fuzzy_search: true
                        wildcard_search: true
                search:
                    service: 'lucene_search'
                    use_frontend_controller: true
                    normalizer:
                        service: 'lucene_document_key_value_normalizer'
                    options:
                        phrased_search: true
                        fuzzy_search: true
                        wildcard_search: true
                    paginator:
                        enabled: true
                        max_per_page: 50
```

Comment: The error message states `Argument #3 ($previousException) must be of type ?Exception, Error given, called in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/vendor/dachcom-digital/dynamic-search-index-provider-lucene/src/DsLuceneBundle/Provider/LuceneIndexProvider.php on line 114`. You may want to have a look at the `Error` that is passed instead of an `Exception`. It will tell you the actual cause, which will help you understand the problem. Without this information, people can only take (educated) guesses.

Comment: Also, [this is the relevant line](https://github.com/dachcom-digital/pimcore-dynamic-search-index-provider-lucene/blob/de06a1044b0a748db2df6d3b109f204647aa71f7/src/DsLuceneBundle/Provider/LuceneIndexProvider.php#L114). The error you are seeing is just a subsequent error. This subsequent error, is a bug in the dynamic-search repo. You probably want to create an issue/PR to solve this. It will then help directly seeing the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: @mcuenez First of all, thank you for spending your time here. What you say, that I need to look at the error instead of the exception is correct and also a good tip. After trying many things, I have a custom config in use. See above. Thank you again for your answers and maybe my example will help jm. else too.